# Librería Clustering Evaluator desactualizada

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, apache-spark, pyspark

Estoy intentando realizar un algoritmo de ML no supervisado, para ello estoy probando con el algoritmo de `K-Means` en `pyspark`. Sin embargo al correr el código de la documentación que es el siguiente:

```
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import ClusteringEvaluator

# Loads data.
dataset = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("data/mllib/sample_kmeans_data.txt")

# Trains a k-means model.
kmeans = KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1)
model = kmeans.fit(dataset)

# Make predictions
predictions = model.transform(dataset)

# Evaluate clustering by computing Silhouette score
evaluator = ClusteringEvaluator()

silhouette = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
print("Silhouette with squared euclidean distance = " + str(silhouette))

# Shows the result.
centers = model.clusterCenters()
print("Cluster Centers: ")
for center in centers:
    print(center)
```

Me salta un error de que la librería `ClusteringEvaluator` no fue encontrada. Alguien sabe si esta librería fue desestimada en alguna versión de `PySpark` o ¿Por qué me sale este error al importar la librería? De antemano gracias.

Les comparto una imagen del error que me aparece:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes poner exatcamente la traza de error completa, para que sea más fácil ayudarte por favor.

Comment: Listo, ya compartí la traza del error

Comment: Gracias :) . Puedes por favor importar la librería ```import pyspark``` y decirme la versión que estás usando con ```pyspark.__version__```.

Comment: Me sale que es la "2.2.1.dev0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres usar `ClusteringEvaluator()` necesitas tener una versión **igual o mayor a la 2.3** Ya que es la versión en la que salió.

- [Documentación pyspark 2.2](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#module-pyspark.ml.evaluation) puedes ver que NO se encuentra.
- [Documentación pyspark 2.3](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#module-pyspark.ml.evaluation) puedes ver que SI se encuentra.

Puedes actualizar a cualquier versión, desinstalando e instalando la versión con el  nombre del paquete y la versión que quieres.

```
pip uninstall pyspark
```

Y después:

```
pip install pyspark==2.3
```

Salió en junio la versión 3. Yo la instalaría si estás empezando a cualquier proyecto. En el caso de que quieras hacer modificaciones en algún proyecto antiguo, instalaría la versión `pyspark 2.4` con `pip install pyspark==2.4`, ya que **entre la versión 2 y la 3 hay cambios significativos** que te pueden traer problemas.